# HTML select tag - How to change the selected multiple foreground color

Tags: html, css

I try to change the default selected item **blue** color, to other color using CSS.

```
 <select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: It's not duplicate I need to change the highlight blue color. the question you bring change the background color, not the selection color. please remove the duplicate, and don't put duplicate again if you don't understand the question.

Comment: And the question I linked to, which I still feel this question duplicates, asks how to change the background-color of the selected option; clearly you feel I was wrong (and if I *am* I'm genuinely sorry and I will reopen): to be sure that I'm not misunderstanding your intent could you clarify what you mean by 'the selection color'? Because I read that to mean the blue background of the selected option(s). Note that if you think I'm being unfair/wrong you can absolutely raise a question on [meta] for community attention.